# Understanding Laravel reationships - they don't make sense...?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

---

I have two tables. This one is called **teams**:

```
+------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------+
|   Column   |     Type     | Null |       Default        | Comments |
+------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------+
| id         | int(10)      | No   |                      |          |
| apikey     | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| name       | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| logo       | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| url        | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| hashtag    | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| created_at | timestamp    | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  |          |
| updated_at | timestamp    | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  |          |
+------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------+
```

The other one is called **streamers**:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------+
|    Column    |     Type     | Null |       Default        | Comments |
+--------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------+
| id           | int(10)      | No   |                      |          |
| apikey       | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| name         | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| team         | int(11)      | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| type         | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| twitch       | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| mlg          | int(11)      | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| url          | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| twitter      | varchar(255) | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| status       | int(11)      | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| viewers      | int(11)      | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
| created_at   | timestamp    | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  |          |
| updated_at   | timestamp    | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  |          |
| last_live    | timestamp    | No   | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  |          |
| last_edit_by | int(11)      | Yes  | NULL                 |          |
+--------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------+
```

As you can see, the **streamers** table has a team field which is only the **team** ID.

My *Team.php* model already has this:

```
public function streamers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Streamer', 'team');
    }
```

---

### Here's what I want to do

I want to search the **streamers** by **team**, HOWEVER the end user should only have to use the name not the ID. How do I make the table relationship so that I can query the **streamers** table for the **team** name instead of the ID? Is this possible at all?

I would've assumed this is exactly what relationship hasOne is for, but apparently I was wrong. Since I obviously don't have the **streamer** ID's in the **team** table because every **streamer** ID on a **team** would be awful. Laravel relationships seems kinda wrong here... Because hasOne would fit on **streamers** but it only works with **teams**, but essentially the **streamers** have a **team** and the **team** belongs to many **streamers** and that would mean belongsToMany would make sense.

### Thanks

Comment: Read this and come back in case of further questions http://softonsofa.com/querying-relations-with-eloquent-in-laravel-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the **belongsTo** relationship.

In **streamers** include:

```
public function team()
{
    $this->belongsTo('Team','team');
}
```

You can then query streamers by team like so:

```
$streamer = Streamer::whereHas('team', function($q)
{
    $q->where('name', 'like', $teamName);

})->get();
```

More details can be found in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations